# Carrying out an ANOVA test from a table of data with multiple columns

Tags: r

Is there a way in R to carry out an ANOVA test from a table of data that looks as follows:

```
Trees Avg_number_1m Avg_number_2m Avg_number_3m Avg_number_4m
1   Tree_1          15.2          15.0          15.2          12.0
2   Tree_2          16.2          15.4          14.2          15.4
3   Tree_3          14.4           9.2           3.2           1.6
4   Tree_4          14.6           5.6          10.4           9.2
5   Tree_5          15.2          13.0           7.4           3.0
6   Tree_6          14.0          12.0          13.0          11.2
7   Tree_7          13.8           7.8           7.2           2.0
8   Tree_8          10.8           5.8           4.4           2.4
9   Tree_9          12.4           9.6           6.8           2.6
10 Tree_10          15.6          11.0           7.2           1.8
11 Tree_11           7.6           7.4           9.0           1.8
12 Tree_12          13.8           7.8           7.2           2.0
13 Tree_13          10.8           5.8           4.4           1.6
14 Tree_14          15.2          15.0          15.2          12.0
15 Tree_15          16.2          15.4          14.2          15.0
16 Tree_16          12.4           9.2           3.2           1.6
17 Tree_17          14.6           5.6          10.4           9.2
18 Tree_18          15.2          13.0           7.4           3.0
19 Tree_19          14.0          14.4          13.2          13.8
20 Tree_20          11.0           5.2           4.4           0.8
```

I've tried to find tutorials on how to do this but the fact that the aov command requires one x and one y variable has been throwing me off. Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Reshape the data into a long format so you have a column for the grouping (1m, 2m, etc) and a column for values

Comment: Hi Idris, your data is a bit different. Do you mind explaining what are the columns and what you would like to test for? This way you will not be performing the wrong test

Comment: Thanks for the reply @StupidWolf. The table is meant to show the numbers of spines on the leaves of holly trees at different heights - each column is a different height (1 metre, 2 metres, 3 metres, 4 metres). I'm looking to carry out an ANOVA test to test the hypothesis that there are fewer spines on leaves at greater heights.

Comment: Ok. Thanks for clarifying, let me write something that can get you started.

Comment: @StupidWolf Amazing, thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So this is your data:

```
x = structure(list(Trees = structure(c(1L, 12L, 14L, 15L, 16L, 17L, 
18L, 19L, 20L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 13L), .Label = c("Tree_1", 
"Tree_10", "Tree_11", "Tree_12", "Tree_13", "Tree_14", "Tree_15", 
"Tree_16", "Tree_17", "Tree_18", "Tree_19", "Tree_2", "Tree_20", 
"Tree_3", "Tree_4", "Tree_5", "Tree_6", "Tree_7", "Tree_8", "Tree_9"
), class = "factor"), Avg_number_1m = c(15.2, 16.2, 14.4, 14.6, 
15.2, 14, 13.8, 10.8, 12.4, 15.6, 7.6, 13.8, 10.8, 15.2, 16.2, 
12.4, 14.6, 15.2, 14, 11), Avg_number_2m = c(15, 15.4, 9.2, 5.6, 
13, 12, 7.8, 5.8, 9.6, 11, 7.4, 7.8, 5.8, 15, 15.4, 9.2, 5.6, 
13, 14.4, 5.2), Avg_number_3m = c(15.2, 14.2, 3.2, 10.4, 7.4, 
13, 7.2, 4.4, 6.8, 7.2, 9, 7.2, 4.4, 15.2, 14.2, 3.2, 10.4, 7.4, 
13.2, 4.4), Avg_number_4m = c(12, 15.4, 1.6, 9.2, 3, 11.2, 2, 
2.4, 2.6, 1.8, 1.8, 2, 1.6, 12, 15, 1.6, 9.2, 3, 13.8, 0.8)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("1", 
"2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "11", "12", "13", 
"14", "15", "16", "17", "18", "19", "20"))
```

We can very quickly visualize your data using boxplot, and it shows that there are fewer spines at greater heights:

[image]

So we load a few libraries to get the data in the correct shape:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(tidyr)

# first we make it a "long" format
df = pivot_longer(x,-Trees,names_to="Height_levels")
```

Now we visualize for each individual tree how it looks like:

```
ggplot(df,aes(x=Height_levels,y=value,col=Trees)) + geom_point() + 
geom_line(aes(group=Trees)) + theme(legend.position="top")
```

[image]

These tells us two things, we need to adjust the Tree, and then test when there are differences between the heights, the most straightfoward is to use an anova to test:

```
aovfit = aov(value ~ Trees + Height_levels,data=df)                    
summary(aovfit)
              Df Sum Sq Mean Sq F value   Pr(>F)    
Trees         19  877.9   46.20   7.692 8.98e-10 ***
Height_levels  3  588.9  196.31  32.682 2.02e-12 ***
Residuals     57  342.4    6.01
```

And post-hoc with Tukey:

```
posthoc = TukeyHSD(aovfit)
posthoc$Height_levels
                             diff      lwr        upr        p adj
Avg_number_2m-Avg_number_1m -3.49 -5.54109 -1.4389103 1.930647e-04
Avg_number_3m-Avg_number_1m -4.77 -6.82109 -2.7189103 4.752523e-07
Avg_number_4m-Avg_number_1m -7.55 -9.60109 -5.4989103 1.182687e-11
Avg_number_3m-Avg_number_2m -1.28 -3.33109  0.7710897 3.586375e-01
Avg_number_4m-Avg_number_2m -4.06 -6.11109 -2.0089103 1.429319e-05
Avg_number_4m-Avg_number_3m -2.78 -4.83109 -0.7289103 3.779450e-03
```

If you would like, you can also fit a linear model, where the height is a continuous variable, and test it with an anova:

```
df$Height = as.numeric(gsub("[^0-9]","",as.character(df$Height_levels)))
aov_continuous = aov(value ~ Trees + Height,data=df)
summary(aov_continuous)

Df Sum Sq Mean Sq F value   Pr(>F)    
Trees       19  877.9    46.2   7.601 7.74e-10 ***
Height       1  572.6   572.6  94.199 7.78e-14 ***
Residuals   59  358.7     6.1
```

And coefficients tell you how much lesser spines on average you get, by going up 1 m. In this case, it's about -2.39..

```
aov_continuous$coefficients
[...]
       Height 
-2.393000e+00
```